# Python: Kivy throws an exception when trying to install it with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, kivy

I am currently trying to install kivy to python 3.6, but when i am trying yo install it it throws the following exception:

```
C:\Users\magshimim\Desktop\notKivy>python -m pip install kivy

 Collecting kivy

   Using cached 

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/e6/e07f77a8d85a626bb955fe072d41042c4c
ee6deaca61295f1c08e6407097/Kivy-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl Collecting Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 (from kivy)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/68/decaee596ff8168a39432eb3949fc7c0be952ebb9467806823bffc165d48/kivy-garden-0.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 175, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 103, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
pip install kivy
```

Worked for me on my Windows machine. Make sure pip is in the *Path* enviornment variable on your machine.

Comment: In what way `python -m pip install kivy` is different from `pip install kivy`?